# Youtube - Resumable upload / connection timeouts

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm using this library to upload videos to YouTube. Since I use this on different locations, and some locations does not have stable connection, I'm getting time-outs when trying to reach Google's servers. (fe. it goes down once per 3 ~300MB files)

**Problem -**
When connection gets back, I re-start the upload of the video, but it does not continue from last successful package sent to YouTube, but it goes from beginning, which is not behaviour I want.

I already store how much of bytes of the video file were successfully stored, but I do not see any way how to tell the `Google_Http_MediaFileUpload :: $progress variable` [GitHub source](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php) Since this is used in this class as-well to create `content-range` header in `nextChunk` method. However `getResumeUri` method looks to provide the same Uri correctly.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this currently not possible?